# Laravel passport API return Exception as HTML instead of JSON response

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

My API has been built with Laravel 5.4 Passport, authorisation and issuing access tokens is working properly, but when dealing with a resource like below using Insomnia or Postman:

```js
Authorization: Bearer [encrypted access token goes here which has only "manage-users" scope]
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

I send above request to this url:

> http://apiendpoint.loc/api/users

which has been restricted access to this recourse to tokens which has this scopes

> manage-users, test-scope-1

```php
Route::get('/users', [
    'as' => 'users', 
    'uses' => 'UsersController@index'
])->middleware(['auth:api', 'scopes:manage-users,test-scope-1']);
```

scopes have been defined in the:

> AuthServiceProvider

```php
Passport::tokensCan([
    'manage-users' => 'testing',
    'test-scope-1' => 'test scope',
    'test-scope-2' => 'another test scope',
]);
```

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    ...,
    ...,
    'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
    'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class        
];
```

The token used to authorize this request has "manage-users" scope only, so I expected to get json response with unauthorized access 401 in addition to the required scope to access this resource which is "test-scope-1".

although I got a HttpException "Invalid scope(s) provided." as HTML response not json

Edit
`Auth-Scaffolding is not installed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I found a way to to work around the issue earlier in the exception handler like below:

```php
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

    // If the request wants JSON (AJAX doesn't always want JSON)
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {

    if($exception instanceof MissingScopeException){
        // Define the response
        $response = [
            'errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
        ];

        // If the app is in debug mode
        if (config('app.debug')) {
            // Add the exception class name, message and stack trace to response
            //$response['exception'] = get_class($exception); // Reflection might be better here
            $response['message'] = $exception->getMessage();
            //$response['trace'] = $exception->getTrace();
        }

        // Default response of 401
        $status = 403;//forbidden

        // If this exception is an instance of HttpException
        if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
            // Grab the HTTP status code from the Exception
            $status = $exception->getStatusCode();
        }

        // Return a JSON response with the response array and status code
        return response()->json($response, $status);
    }

    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

so I'll be able to catch the error early and return a json object as a response.